# Shrinking cwd path in oh-my-bash powerline

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm using oh-my-bash's powerline theme and the the cwd prompt sometimes gets too long. I found this in the `powerline.base.sh` file, which I assume is returning the pwd:

```
function __powerline_cwd_prompt {
    echo "$(pwd | sed "s|^${HOME}|~|")|${CWD_THEME_PROMPT_COLOR}"
}
```

I wish to modify this such that long directories will be compressed e.g something like ~/stuff/moreStuff/.../now. I do not know much BASH so I was wondering how about should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be surprised if *oh-my-bash* didn't have an option/function to shorten paths.

Nevertheless, here's a quick attempt at a shortener (shortens from the start, as tends to be the tradition):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841619/2858703
join_by() { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }

short_pwd() {
  IFS='/' read -a directory < <(pwd)

  local -i trim_level=${1:-3} # default trim level of 3

  if [ ${#directory[*]} -ge ${trim_level} ] && [ ${trim_level} -gt 0 ]; then
    join_by / "..." "${directory[@]: -${trim_level}}"
  else
    pwd
  fi
}

# examples
short_pwd
short_pwd 2
# these cause no trimming
short_pwd 0
short_pwd -1
short_pwd a
```

In its current form, you would need to `.` source this (removing the examples) to make use of it.  Or replace the examples with `short_pwd $1` at the end, and you can run it as a script (first passed parameter determines the trim level).

With acknowledgments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841619/2858703).

(I realise this is a problem that has probably been solved many times before, but sometimes it's fun to try to roll your own.)

EDIT: realised I had over-engineered.  Now with added elegance!